# Can I use ms flow "peek code"/json to setup new flows?

Tags: power-automate

We use Sharepoint for our project files and that means there are often several layers of work to be done (project work, finances, administrative, etc) with different teams and working in different locations. There are some folders that I would like to keep "in sync" by copying files back and forth on change. I made some flows to do so, but it is pretty tedious as there are 6 sub directories for each project and a bunch of projects.

I noticed the peek code is pretty simple, it is just the name part of the directory that needs to change. Is there any way to manually define a flow or some way I can use the json/peek code to setup a flow?

For reference, I am using the sharepoint "when a file is created or modified (properties only)" and copy file flow. My directory structure looks like the following.

Thanks!

Projects Team:

```
ProjectNumber ProjectName

   projNumber Administrative

                projNumber invoices

                           projNumber Received 

                           projNumber Sent

                           projNumber Requested
```

Accounting Team:

```
Invoices

   projNumber projName 

                           projNumber Received 

                           projNumber Sent

                           projNumber Requested
```

Comment: Have you tried exporting your flow and modyfing the underlying source code? I am quite sure it will be possible

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but still, it is not recommended. Because if you end up with some different hierarchy it may cause a severe impact. Anyway, let me put it in steps:-

1. Export your existing Flow.
2. Open the exported .zip file, it should have a file called ***definition.json***.
3. Search for the exact hierarchy you are looking for and **replace the hierarchy with what you have**.
4. Compress it to `.zip` file.
5. Now go to https://us.flow.microsoft.com/
6. In the My Flows tab, click on import. import the compressed `.zip` file in step 4.
7. You are done. It should be working, if not **->** Make sure you have followed JSON syntax throughout the file.